# RAML, Request parameter title not defined

Tags: java, hibernate, url, yaml, raml

I have am having some trouble with my RAML file.

when I call this URL in GET:

```
mysite.com/test/nextversion?msn=xxx&ata=xx&title=xxx
```

it tells me that the parameters are not defined:

```
"Request parameter msn not defined in RAML\nRequest parameter title not defined in RAML\nRequest parameter ata not defined in RAML"
```

This is my RAML definition:

```
/test/nextversion:
  get:
    queryParameters:
      msn:
        description: msn id
        type: string
        required: false
      title:
        description: ata title
        type: string
        required: false
      ata:
        description: ata id
        type: string
        required: false
    responses:
      200:
        description: OK
        body:
          application/json:
            type: string
      550:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: DefaultResponse

/test/{ipid}/nextversion:
  uriParameters:
    ipid:
      type: string
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        description: OK
        body:
          application/json:
            type: string
      550:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: DefaultResponse
```

Now I have noticed that it always goes into the second one cause when I remove the first definition it gives me the same error, even though it shoul tell me that it cant find the right definition.
When I remove the second definition it works fine but I have another endpoint depending on that one.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working in my RAML file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's all about the order of the RAML url definitions.

It should go from most specific to most general case cause the RAML will stop at the first url definition that fits, which is not always the right one.

In my case the request was actually going into a url definition defined before the ones described in my question, cause it fit the url definition minus everything comming after it.